# How to translate this phrase from English to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What's the best way to translate "It's okay to look back as long as you continue to move forward" into latin?

Answer (score 1):

"*It's OK to look back as long as you continue moving forward.*" would be "*Sanum est retro spectare dum directe ire persistas.*".

Comment: Not a bad translation, but instead of *directe*, I'd opt for *prorsus*.